# Efficient count or tabulation of a factor by other factors and reshaping in a data.frame?

Tags: r, data.table, performance

I search for an efficient way to compute the cummulative sum (the tabulation) of all vector levels of a vector while using data.table.

#### The problem

A dataframe/data.table DT initially, consists of four variables, one is named *experience*. The goal is a vector which holds the cumulative counts of factor levels in *experience* conditional two other variables, *id* and *cl*. It is noteworthy that the factor *experience* has more factor levels than are present in the data set (this is a necessary property).

The data looks like

```
    id trial experience cl
 1:  1     1       000A  A
 2:  1     2       000A  A
 3:  1     3       000B  B
 4:  1     4       111A  A
 5:  1     5       001B  B
 6:  2     1       100B  B
 7:  2     2       111A  A
 8:  2     3       100B  B
 9:  2     4       010A  A
10:  2     5       011B  B
```

The factor levels of *experience* are of magnitude 16

```
levels(DT$experience)
#  [1] "000A" "001A" "010A" "011A" "100A" "101A" "110A" "111A"
#  [9] "000B" "001B" "010B" "011B" "100B" "101B" "110B" "111B"
```

What we want to compute is a cummulative count for experience conditional on  *id* and *cl*. Consider the first three lines: For *id*=1 the first experience value is 000A, so a counter variable *c000A* = 1. The second experience value is also 000A, so the counter *c000A* = 2. But now the third experience value is 000B, and so the previous counter *c000A* stays 2, but another counter *c000B* = 1, which was 0 before that.

Following this logic, the result we want looks like:

```
    id trial experience cl c000A c001A c010A c011A c100A c101A c110A c111A c000B c001B c010B c011B c100B c101B c110B c111B
 1:  1     1       000A  A     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2:  1     2       000A  A     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3:  1     3       000B  B     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4:  1     4       111A  A     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5:  1     5       001B  B     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 6:  2     1       100B  B     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 7:  2     2       111A  A     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 8:  2     3       100B  B     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     2     0     0     0
 9:  2     4       010A  A     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     2     0     0     0
10:  2     5       011B  B     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     2     0     0     0
```

**Note**: It is not important to me to assig the 16 entries *c000A, ..., c111B* to separate columns. It would be totally sufficient if the result was one vector with 16 entries ordered as c000A, c001A, ..., c110B, c111B which holds the cummulative counts.

#### Current code and speed of the calculation

The current code I use is the following two-step approach. It is neither beautiful nor elegant.

```
foo <- function(DT){
   # tabulate experience for each trial
   # store in an auxiliary variables <s000A, s001A, ..., s110B, s111B>
   DT[, paste(sep="","s",levels(DT$experience)) := as.list(table(experience)), by = c("id","cl","trial")]
   # sum each of the s____ variables by id
   DT[, "c000A" := cumsum(s000A), by = id] # this is clumsy
   DT[, "c001A" := cumsum(s001A), by = id]
   DT[, "c010A" := cumsum(s010A), by = id]
   DT[, "c011A" := cumsum(s011A), by = id]
   DT[, "c100A" := cumsum(s100A), by = id]
   DT[, "c101A" := cumsum(s101A), by = id]
   DT[, "c110A" := cumsum(s110A), by = id]
   DT[, "c111A" := cumsum(s111A), by = id]
   DT[, "c000B" := cumsum(s000B), by = id]
   DT[, "c001B" := cumsum(s001B), by = id]
   DT[, "c010B" := cumsum(s010B), by = id]
   DT[, "c011B" := cumsum(s011B), by = id]
   DT[, "c100B" := cumsum(s100B), by = id]
   DT[, "c101B" := cumsum(s101B), by = id]
   DT[, "c110B" := cumsum(s110B), by = id]
   DT[, "c111B" := cumsum(s111B), by = id]
}
```

This code takes, for a dataset with n = 1e+4 trials and 2 ids:

```
system.time(foo(DT))
# User  System verstrichen 
# 9.78    0.00       10.05
```

#### Code to create this example

```
library("data.table")
library("R.utils")
# Sample dataframe DF with n=1e+4
n <- 1e+4 #to test change this to n=5
DT <- data.table(id = rep(1:2,each=n), trial = rep(1:n,2), experience = c("000A","000A","000B","111A","001B","100B","111A","100B","010A","011B"), cl = c("A","A","B","A","B","B","A","B","A","B")) # experience needs to be a factor w more levels
DT$experience <- factor(DT$experience, levels = paste(sep="", intToBin(0:7), rep(c("A","B"),each=8)))
setkey(DT,id,trial,cl) #set the data.table keys
```

Who has a faster and more elegant solution?

Thanks!
Jana

---

#### Update: Speed comparisons:

```
library("microbenchmark")
benchmk <- microbenchmark(
   DT2  <- foo2(DT),
   DT3a <- foo3a(DT),
   DT3b <- foo3b(DT),
   times=100L
   )
print(benchmk)

# with n=1e+4
#
# unit milliseconds
#              expr      min       lq   median        uq      max neval
# DT2   <- foo2(DT) 46.96745 52.17469 74.72479 120.93339 212.7912   100
# DT3a <- foo3a(DT) 25.21907 26.57921 28.84702  34.89401 121.3164   100
# DT3b <- foo3b(DT) 19.82076 20.80570 22.87369  30.83561 148.0520   100 

# with n=1e+5
#
# unit milliseconds
#              expr       min       lq   median       uq       max neval
#   DT2 <- foo2(DT) 386.93890 445.0184 481.4660 534.9619 1160.6151   100
# DT3a <- foo3a(DT) 144.45937 154.5672 170.6048 233.6362  494.8972   100
# DT3b <- foo3b(DT)  95.91988 100.5313 110.4060 125.1678  364.5651   100
```

foo2 corresponds to Eddi's code

```
foo2 <- function(DT){
    DT[, counter := 1:.N]
    DT[, dummy := 1]
    RE <- dcast.data.table(DT, counter+id ~ experience, value.var = 'dummy', fill = 0)[,lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = id, .SDcols = c(-1,-2)]
    RE[, setdiff(levels(DT$experience), unique(DT$experience)) := 0]
    setcolorder(RE, c("id",levels(DT$experience)))
}
```

foo3a correspond's to Arun's first code using the level

```
foo3a <- function(DT){
   ex = levels(DT$experience)
   DT[, c(ex) := 0L]
   tmp = DT[, list(list(.I)), by=experience]
   tmp[, experience := as.character(experience)] ## convert to char
   for(i in seq(nrow(tmp))) {
      set(DT, i=tmp$V1[[i]], j=tmp$experience[i], val=1L)
   }
   DT[, c(ex) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by=id, .SDcols=ex]
}
```

foo3b corresponds to Arun's code using characters

```
foo3b <- function(DT){
   ex = levels(DT$experience)
   DT[, c(ex) := 0L]
   tmp = DT[, list(list(.I)), by=experience]
   tmp[, experience := as.character(experience)] ## convert to char
   for(i in seq(nrow(tmp))) {
      set(DT, i=tmp$V1[[i]], j=tmp$experience[i], val=1L)
   }
   ex = as.character(unique(DT$experience)) ## rewrite 'ex'
   DT[, c(ex) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by=id, .SDcols=ex]
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, just edited it: `library("R.utils")`

Comment: Yes, it can. A sequence as you display it is possible.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The count is cumulative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

First create all the columns and initialise them to 0L.

```
ex = levels(DT$experience)
DT[, c(ex) := 0L]
```

Now, group by `experience` and get the row numbers corresponding to each `experience` in a list as follows:

```
tmp = DT[, list(list(.I)), by=experience]
tmp[, experience := as.character(experience)] ## convert to char
```

Then, you can loop thro' each column and use `set` with the corresponding rows (from the column `V1`) and the columns (from column `experience`) from `tmp` to assign `1` to the corresponding columns in `DT` as follows:

```
for(i in seq(nrow(tmp))) {
    set(DT, i=tmp$V1[[i]], j=tmp$experience[i], val=1L)
}
```

Finally a `cumsum` on each column by `id`:

```
DT[, c(ex) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by=id, .SDcols=ex]
```

Altogether it took 0.013 seconds (the `dcast.data.table` solution, which is nice as well, took 0.027 seconds).

---

You might be able to save a bit more time if you use `as.character(unique(DT$experience))` instead of `ex` in the last line.. as some columns have all 0's and you don't have to `cumsum` them. That is:

```
ex = as.character(unique(DT$experience)) ## rewrite 'ex'
DT[, c(ex) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by=id, .SDcols=ex]
```

Comment: +1 - this is way faster that `dcast` for larger data

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks a lot. I will add some more benchmarks above.

Comment: That's the solution. Do you have an intuition why the code using a for-loop is the fastest when most recommendations regarding speed go in the direction to avoid loops?

Comment: @JBJ, I'd guess that's the case if you loop over millions of entries. Then it'd be performant if you move the for-loop to C. Here it's just looping a few times. If we implement `set` to be able to do the looping in C and avoid the for-loop here, I'd think that it'd be faster (not here though as it's really a very few columns).

Comment: Also, you can skip `tmp` and `for-loop` altogether and do: `DT[, set(DT, i=.I, j=as.character(experience), value=1L), by=experience]`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps:

```
# add some extra variables
DT[, counter := 1:.N]
DT[, dummy := 1]

dcast.data.table(DT, counter+id ~ experience, value.var = 'dummy', fill = 0)[,
  lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = id, .SDcols = c(-1,-2)]
#       id 000A 010A 111A 000B 001B 011B 100B
#    1:  1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#    2:  1    2    0    0    0    0    0    0
#    3:  1    2    0    0    1    0    0    0
#    4:  1    2    0    1    1    0    0    0
#    5:  1    2    0    1    1    1    0    0
#   ---                                      
#19996:  2 2000  999 1999 1000 1000  999 1999
#19997:  2 2000  999 2000 1000 1000  999 1999
#19998:  2 2000  999 2000 1000 1000  999 2000
#19999:  2 2000 1000 2000 1000 1000  999 2000
#20000:  2 2000 1000 2000 1000 1000 1000 2000
```

And you can `cbind` it back if you like.

Comment: Thanks. On the one hand, the speed is much faster than my solution (wow!) (`User   System   verstrichen | 0.05   0.00   0.05`). But on the other hand, note, that the result needs to display the count for all factor levels. This result displays the counts of the present, nonzero factor levels.

Comment: @JBJ just add the rest as 0 columns by hand, e.g.: `DT.res[, setdiff(levels(DT$experience), unique(DT$experience)) := 0]`, where `DT.res` is the final result above

Comment: Yes, nice! And, as I need the columns in the order of the factor experience, I will reorder them using `setcolorder`. Let me add the speed comparison to the results and see if someone gets sth. faster.